# Realtime apply filter using AVCaptureVideoDataOutput and write buffer to file

Tags: ios, swift, video, avfoundation, video-processing

I'am developing camera application in `Swift`, that edit every frame realtime.

*So what I need:*

1. Edit every frame using `CIFilter` - probably using `AVCaptureVideoDataOutput`
2. Write data buffer to `AVAssetWriter`
3. Add audio
4. Add some labels to the video
5. Realtime view of what camera "see", but already edited by `CIFilter`

*What I have:*

I'am able to edit video output and show it to screen using `imageView`. But I think that this is not best way to do that and with iPhone 4S I have really low FPS:

```
func captureOutput(captureOutput: AVCaptureOutput!, didOutputSampleBuffer sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer!, fromConnection connection: AVCaptureConnection!)
{
    guard let filter = Filters["Saturation"]

    let pixelBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer)
    let cameraImage = CIImage(CVPixelBuffer: pixelBuffer!)

    filter!.setValue(cameraImage, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)

    let filteredImage = UIImage(CIImage: filter!.valueForKey(kCIOutputImageKey) as! CIImage!)

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue())
        {
            self.imageView.image = filteredImage
    }

}
```

So how to change my code to edit frame more efficiently, show it to screen and when its needed write it to a file (I know, that I must convert filtred image to `CMSampleBuffer`, but I don't know how to use `NSTime`)?

Comment: did you find a solution for this?